# Google Hangouts chat not sending notifications

Tags: sms, google-hangouts

I am using Hangouts for both google chat and for text messaging. When I get a chat message my phone doesn't notify me, but when I get a text message I do get a notification. I have missed many messages via chat because of this. Is there anything that I can do to fix this issue?

This used to work, and all of a sudden it stopped working. I have no idea what happened, if it was an update or if I changed a setting not realizing it would affect this.

I have looked through all hangouts settings and I can't seem to find anything that would be causing the issue.

I have tried clearing the data, and I got a few notifications right away, but it didn't solve the issue.

Comment: Would  third-party support be fine with you? An [tag:automation] app, such as Tasker and MacroDroid can easily identify a notification from a particular app and do something for you, such as vibrating, ringing and more.

Comment: I would rather not have to use a third-party app...

Answer (score 0):

go to settings/date & time/automatic date and time (enable"Use network-provided time.“) I do this and the notification start coming to me.

Comment: alright, I have done so. I then sent a message from my work to my personal and nothing. But maybe because my computer caught the notification.... I will have to look a little more...